# Two foreign keys referring to one table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, unique

I am building the backend of a chat system for which I have a `Message` table which looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I need 2 foreign keys pointing on the same table ID.

No problem, but in the case, that a user sends multiple messages, the database says

> unique constraint violated

Example:

```
13  Testmessage1    01.06.17 08:15:01,456554000    2 (sender_id)    23 (receiver_id)
14  Testmessage2    01.06.17 07:09:08,517000000    2 (sender_id)    23 (receiver_id)
```

The two last identifiers are the User Id's which are both the same!

How can I handle that?

Comment: Well, if a single message might have multiple recipients, You want to create a table for message recipients, and use it for a many to many relationship between the message and the recipient id.

Comment: A message has exactly one recipient, not multiply. I have a User Table. The Message Table has to Foreignkeys for the User-ID. If a Sender writes multiple messages to the same user it brings the "unique constraint violated" error. Thats the problem! I also set the two keys on unique=False.

Comment: Then your unique constraint is wrong. It can't be based only on sender and receiver ids, you must also include something else in it.

Comment: Show the structure of user table as well and show either the create statements of both, or show all the constraints on both the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Solved**
I looked at my Constraints and i saw, that i have combined the unique constraints in my Django Model. I deleted that, and migrated my Database, and now i can create multiple Messages. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

The design seems fine to me, but the key you define on that `Messages` table should be different. It's perfectly fine that user X sends a message to user Y multiple times, so I see two options for you to define the key:

- `sender_id` / `receiver_id` / `gendate`: it shouldn't happen that two messages from the same user to the same user are sent at the same time
- `ID`: you're already providing a surrogate key, you can use that

**Edit (further explaination)**

When you define a table, you can also define uniqueness constraints on it.

Let's assume your table has a unique key defined as (`sender_id`, `receiver_id`); with that, you're telling the dbms "hey, don't let me insert two messages with the same values of `sender_id` and `receiver_id`, because those are the criterias I want to use to uniquely identify a row". This way, whenever you pick a sender and a receiver, you're sure that you will get no more than one message.

If you have a row with values 2 and 23 in your table, trying to insert another one with those same values results in that error message.

My first option says that if you change that unique key to also include `gendate` instead, the dbms will assure you that there won't be two rows with the same `sender_id`, `receiver_id` AND `gendate` values. The rows that are causing your error would then be considered different.

The second option says that if your unique key is `ID`, you can even have multiple messages between the same users at the same time, as long as you generate a different `ID` value for each row you insert.

Comment: Isn´t Option 1 the same structure as i have?

Comment: The table structure doesn't need to be changed, either option you choose; what needs to be changed is the constraint you defined on it. Your current key is probably defined as (`sender_id` / `receiver_id`), and my first option adds `gendate` to that; this way the two rows that are currently violating the uniqueness constraint will be acceptable, because they differ for `gendate`

Comment: Sorry, but can you maybe give me an example? I dont really understand what you mean

Comment: I see you found the solution to your problem, nevertheless I updated my answer, should someone else stumble upon your question in the future.

Comment: Ah okay now iam understanding what your opinion is ^^.

Answer (score 0):

The key is not to violate the uniqueness constraint, I think the problem is not here, you need to provide a complete table structure, I do not understand one thing, why do we have to set up a foreign key, I think this will reduce the system flexibility and maintainability, increase a little difficulty for the development, I think we should get rid of the foreign key.